# How can I make Spring load classes from a given URL (for bean instantiation)?

Tags: java, spring, urlclassloader

Is there a way to tell Spring to load classes from a given URL while instantiating the beans? I need to load classes from a location that is not in the classpath. If I were using pure Java, I could use `URLClassLoader` but how can I achieve this in Spring? I am using Spring 3.0

Comment: What about [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.setClassLoader()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html#setClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader))?

Comment: Looks promising, but will the application context use this class loader to load bean classes? It certainly will use it to load resources specified in an applicationContext.xml file.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968920) question and... just try it :-).

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, I think this is the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Spring classes that extend [`DefaultResourceLoader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html) can have an explicit `ClassLoader` reference set (via [`DefaultResourceLoader.setClassLoader(ClassLoader)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html#setClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

[`AbstractApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html) happens to be one of those classes. So all ApplicationContext implementations that extend it (like `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and  `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`) can use an injected `ClassLoader` reference.

Comment: Thanks Dev. Thanks to Tomasz as well who suggested the same solution in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutodeployConfiguration.class);

        URL[] files = {
            new File("C:\\module1.jar").toURL(),
            new File("C:\\propertiesdirectory\\").toURL()
        };

        URLClassLoader plugin = new URLClassLoader(files, Main.class.getClassLoader());
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(plugin);

        Class startclass = plugin.loadClass("de.module1.YourModule");
        ExternalModule start = (ExternalModule) startclass.newInstance();
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ivr = start.onDeploy(plugin, ctx);
    }
}


public class YourModule implements ExternalModule {

    @Override
    public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext onDeploy(ClassLoader classloader, GenericApplicationContext parent) {      
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setClassLoader(classloader);
        applicationContext.setParent(parent);
        applicationContext.register(ModuleConcreteConfiguration.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();


        // other code

        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```